# Does boost::future then have any limitation of its length?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, future

I believe that we can take a then of a then. For example,

```
boost::future<void> f1 = boost::async(...);
boost::future<void> f2 = f1.then(...);
boost::future<void> f3 = f2.then(...);
...
```

How long could this continuation chain be? It is safe if we have a long then/then/then chain.

Thank you,

Comment: If it is supported for `f1`, why would anyone think it is not supported for `f2` and so on? Are not all of them `future` and thus *semantically identical*?

Comment: @Nawaz How I had thought it could be implemented as a recursive call to chain all calls. If so, it would run overflow stacks. If this is not the case, I guess there would not be any limitation?

Comment: No. It is not recursive.... and it cannot be recursive; because the callback of `f1` does not call the callback of `f2`; it is rather like : `callback1` returns, then `callback2` is called, one *after* another, **not** one *from* another.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits set by the library. `then` is a member function of `boost::future` which returns a `boost::future`. So you can effectively chain these up to the limits of the hardware. It's probably a good idea to keep the logic of them maintainable though by limiting them in scope in the same way functions should be limited.

Comment: by 'the limits of the hardware', did you mean # of threads? I had thought for a chained then, one thread would be sufficient. Is this not what 'then' does internally?

Comment: By limitation of hardware I mean that code takes up space in memory and so chaining them will use memory. i.e. `myFuture.then(a).then(b)...then(...)`.